# TestComplete - How to define dynamic variable in testComplete like we do in Soapui with $ sign "${#Var2}"

Tags: variables, dynamic, testcomplete

Ive got two project level variables in TestComplete:

Var1 = ${#Var2}    and  Var2 = 123456789

using **Log.Message(Project.Variables.Var1)** should evaluate to "**123456789**" but it just prints **${#Var2}** as string.

is there any way we can make it dynamic?

in particular I want to update the value of a variable defined in "ReadyAPI-Test Edit-Properties" page with the value from project's local or persistent property value. The reason is that this variable is not accessible using script, the only option available is to execute i.e. ReadyAPI.TestCase.Execute()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is usually done in TestComplete.

If you need to use this in a script, you can use the **eval** function. However, the syntax of the variable should contain a valid JavaScript code:
Var1 = "Var2"
Var2 = 123456789

Log.Message(eval(Var1));

If you do not have control over the format of the Var1 variable, you will need to create code that will parse the value of the variable and do the needed replacements.